# How to center text inside an svg element on Firefox?

Tags: css, svg

Inside my svg element I have this text element:

```
<text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
```

This vertically centers the element on Chrome but it fails on Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/g398ajc0/1/

How to make it work everywhere?

(also is there any way to move it a few pixels around if the font isn't well aligned? Margin or top/bottom don't seem to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to the Mozilla docs, "alignment-baseline" and "text-anchor" aren't officially supported in the  tag, so you will have to use x and y positions instead. [(Link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text)

So what I found that seemed to look the best was this:

```
<svg viewBox="-20,-20,40,40" class="progress-ring">
    <circle r="20" class="progress-ring-circle"></circle>
    <path d="M0,-20 A20,20,0,0,1,6.180339887498949,-19.02113032590307" 
    class="progress-ring-ring" style="stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></path>
    <text dx="-4" dy="5"> 1 </text>
</svg>
```

Though, you could probably mess around a little more to get it completely centered the way you want it.